# Can we change the size of size_t in C?

Tags: c, size-t

Can we change the size of `size_t` in C?

Comment: Is this a setup for one of those "pranks to play on fellow programmers" questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`size_t` is not a macro. It is a `typedef` for a suitable unsigned integer type.

`size_t` is defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers).

It probably is `typedef unsigned long long size_t;` and you **really** should not even think about changing it. **The Standard Library uses it as defined by the Standard Library.** If you change it, *as you cannot change the Standard Library*, you'll get all kinds of errors because your program uses a different size for size_t than the Standard Library. You can no longer call `malloc()`, `strncpy()`, `snprintf()`, ...

Comment: It's probably either `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long  long`, depending on the maximum object size supported by the compiler.

Answer (score 8):

No. But why would you even want to do it?

Comment: i want to locate where size_t macro is and see how it is implemented

Comment: @tsubasa: Then that is a different question entirely.

Comment: It's probably a typedef rather than a macro.

Comment: `size_t` is a typedef-name, not a macro.

Answer (score 1):

#### If you want to fork Linux or NetBSD, then "Yes"

Although you can redefine macros this one is probably a typedef.

If you are defining an environment then it's perfectly reasonable to specify `size_t` as you like. You will then be responsible for all the C99 standard functions for which conforming code expects `size_t`.

So, it depends on your situation. If you are developing an application for an existing platform, then the answer is **no**.

But if you are defining an original environment with one or more compilers, then the answer is **yes**, but you have your work cut out for you. You will need an implementation of all the library routines with an API element of `size_t` which can be compiled with the rest of your code with the new `size_t` typedef. So, if  you fork NetBSD or Linux, perhaps for an embedded system, then go for it. Otherwise, you may well find it "not worth the effort".